# Android project with CustomListView nullPoinTerException error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I'm getting error while building an alarm project. Here is logcat:

```
 at com.example.user.packname.Adapter.<init>(Adapter.java:25)
 at com.example.user.packname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
```

Here Adapter:

```
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
public Adapter(Context context1, int resource1, List<Time> objects) {
    super(context1, resource1, objects);
    resource = resource1;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context1 );
    context=context1;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    convertView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
    Time Legend = getItem( position );
    TextView legendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    legendName.setText(Legend.getTime());

    TextView legendBorn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    legendBorn.setText(Legend.getRepeating());

    ImageView legendImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    String uri = "drawable/" + Legend.getImageResource();
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    legendImage.setImageDrawable(image);
    return convertView;
}
```

25 line: context = context1;

MainActivity:

```
ctx = this;
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final List<Time> brat = new ArrayList<Time>();
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("timedb", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists TIME"+" ("+ "times" +" VARCHAR(100)"+");");
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TIME; ", null);
    i = 0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        uns[i] = cursor.getString(0);
        brat.add(new Time(uns[i], "Mon", "ic_cars", "#fff"));
        i++;
                }
    t = i;
    listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(ctx, R.layout.adapter, brat));
```

(Everything in oncreate() method.)

Here Values =

```
String uns[] = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "","","",""};
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;
int i, t =0;
Context ctx;
final List<Time> brat = new ArrayList<Time>();
```

I am quietly sure that the problem not in sqlite but in my custom listview (because I tried with simple listview and everything worked).

Comment: check if your List<Time> is not null when init the adapter

Comment: yes it's null. But at the starting it mustn't have any values. How to fix it?

Comment: From your activity you are passing an Activity but from your Adapter you are receiving it as a context. You should pass ctx.getApplicationContext() from Main Activity

Comment: The list can be empty but not null, but it's look like it is ok in your code. Do you have the error thrown in the logcat?

Comment: fixed it by declaring List<Time> before oncreate(). But now I have another problem: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; Thanks For all!